# OpenStackCLI: Access `--property`'s from cloudinit script

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, cloud-init

Using the OpenStack CLI, I am creating server instances and need to pass custom properties (`--property`) into the init script referenced by the `--user-data` parameter.

So, my invocation looks something like this:

```
openstack server create myServer \
  ...other args...
  --user-data ./initScript.sh \
  --property "foo=bar"
```

In `initScript.sh` how do I get access to the `foo` property and it's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements defined with `--property` go into the `meta` element of the metadata. [[source](https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/python-openstackclient/tree/openstackclient/compute/v2/server.py?id=16aeee430308fd1863d2f9892f09e0d928a0e6f1#n608)]

If you run

```bash
curl http://169.254.169.254/openstack/2018-08-27/meta_data.json
```

You'll get

```json
{
   "hostname": "test.novalocal",
   …
   "meta": {
      "foo": "bar",
      …
   },
   …
}
```

And to parse out the value in a shell script, you can use for example:

```bash
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/openstack/2018-08-27/meta_data.json \
    | jq -r '.meta.foo'
bar
```

See documentation for the [Metadata Service](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/user/metadata.html#metadata-openstack-format) for more information on the format and various methods available to retrieve this information.